# Tabs component not rendering in Ionic Capacitor app after building in Android Studio

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I've run into a very interesting problem with my Ionic Capacitor mobile app when building in Android.

I have a very simple app that is using a Tabs component to navigate between a home page and an info page. When running the app in either the dev server on my machine or on my device using Live Reload, the app functions as normal, the tabs appear and I can navigate between the pages as expected.

The issue arises when I either run the app from Android Studio directly to my device or generate a APK/Bundle and execute it on my device. When running the app after installing the generated APK/Bundle, the tabs are not rendered and I am at a loss as to why that is? I have tried both release and debug builds and they both show the same issue.

Any help or advice is much appreciated!

**Running dev with Live Reload**
[image: app running in dev]

**Running APK**

Apologies as I couldn't capture the console log for this pic, but as you can see the Tabs are not rendered here.

The same happens if I simply run the app from Android.

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaHVv.png)

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic cap run android -l --external",
    "build:android": "ionic cap build android",
    "build:ios": "ionic cap build ios",
    "sync": "npx cap sync",
    "repair": "ionic repair",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor-community/barcode-scanner": "^2.0.1",
    "@capacitor-community/screen-brightness": "^1.0.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "3.4.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.4.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.4",
    "@capacitor/ios": "3.4.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.1",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^1.2.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.7",
    "@capacitor/storage": "^1.2.4",
    "@ionic-native/dialogs": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/react": "^6.0.0",
    "@ionic/react-router": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.22",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
    "ionicons": "^5.5.4",
    "qrcode": "^1.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-broadcast-update": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-cacheable-response": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-core": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-expiration": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-google-analytics": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-navigation-preload": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-precaching": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-range-requests": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-routing": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-strategies": "^5.1.4",
    "workbox-streams": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.42",
    "@types/qrcode": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.14",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "cordova-res": "^0.15.4",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.4",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

**Ionic Version**

```
6.16.3
```

**Gradle Version**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.7.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-11-16 17:09:24 UTC
Revision:     2972ff02f3210d2ceed2f1ea880f026acfbab5c0

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          15.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 15.0.2+7-27)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

**Android Gradle Plugin Version**

```
4.2.0
```

**Build Output**

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\ionic\app\android

AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Using flatDirs should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.\nCurrently detected usages:\n- repository flatDir used in: project ':app', project ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins'","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and migrate your build to other Maven repositories.\nThis repository is deprecated and it will be shut down in the future.\nSee http://developer.android.com/r/tools/jcenter-end-of-service for more information.\nCurrently detected usages in: root project 'android', project ':app', project ':capacitor-android', ...","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (29.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (30.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.0.\nAndroid SDK Build Tools 30.0.2 will be used.\nTo suppress this warning, remove \"buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'\" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.","sources":[{}]}
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-storage:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-android:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-storage:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-android:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-storage:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE

> Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug

> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\ionic\driver-app\qrcode-app\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\dialogs\Notification.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :capacitor-haptics:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-android:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-storage:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-android:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-android:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-storage:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-storage:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
> Task :capacitor-android:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-android:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-android:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-android:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-haptics:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-storage:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :capacitor-storage:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions

> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\ionic\driver-app\qrcode-app\node_modules\@capacitor-community\barcode-scanner\android\src\main\java\com\dutchconcepts\capacitor\barcodescanner\BarcodeScanner.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
> Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :capacitor-haptics:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug

> Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :capacitor-keyboard:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug

> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\ionic\driver-app\qrcode-app\node_modules\@capacitor\splash-screen\android\src\main\java\com\capacitorjs\plugins\splashscreen\SplashScreen.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug

> Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\ionic\driver-app\qrcode-app\node_modules\@capacitor\status-bar\android\src\main\java\com\capacitorjs\plugins\statusbar\StatusBar.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :capacitor-status-bar:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
> Task :capacitor-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :capacitor-community-barcode-scanner:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-community-screen-brightness:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
> Task :capacitor-haptics:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-keyboard:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-splash-screen:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-status-bar:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :capacitor-storage:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :app:compileDebugSources
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug
> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug
> Task :app:packageDebug
> Task :app:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
181 actionable tasks: 33 executed, 148 up-to-date

Build Analyzer results available
```

**Android Studio Version**

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1
```

**JDK Version**

```
jdk1.8.0_202
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be good, if you send us the errors you are getting. But let me try to explain. It can be a mistake on the `tabs-routing.module.ts` file. So, let the field `path: ''` empty on the route like the example below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for taking the time to answer.

>It should be good, if you send us the errors you are getting.<

That is the thing I am not receiving any errors that I can see. The app builds just fine, it's just for some reason the Tabs are not rendering in the APK/Bundle I build.

Comment: The suggested doesn't work for you? Let me know...